# Username from other table by foreign key

Tags: mysql, yii2

First table :
user_id - primary key
username
password

Second table:
user_equip_id - primary key
phone_model
phone_model_series
phone_date_acq
nb_sg_model
nb_sg_date_acq
display_model
display_series
display_date_acq
user_for_id - foreign key to user_id from table1

I want when i see equipemnts to be associated to an username, but when i go to view it says it's **not set** even if i have made the function getUsername in model. I don't know how to get the username from the first table associated by foreign key. If you can give any help i thank you very much.

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Equipment;
use app\models\EquipmentSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * EquipmentController implements the CRUD actions for Equipment model.
 */
class EquipmentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Equipment models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new EquipmentSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Equipment model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Equipment model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Equipment();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_equip_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Equipment model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_equip_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Equipment model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Equipment model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Equipment the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Equipment::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "equipment".
 *
 * @property int $user_equip_id
 * @property string|null $phone_model
 * @property string $phone_series
 * @property string $phone_date_acq
 * @property string $nb_sg_model
 * @property string $nb_sg_series
 * @property string $nb_sg_date_acq
 * @property string $display_model
 * @property string $display_series
 * @property string $display_date_acq
 * @property int $user_for_id
 *
 * @property User $userFor
 */
class Equipment extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'equipment';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['phone_series', 'phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_model', 'display_series', 'display_date_acq', 'user_for_id'], 'required'],
            [['phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_date_acq'], 'safe'],
            [['user_for_id'], 'integer'],
            [['phone_model', 'phone_series', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'display_model', 'display_series'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['user_for_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_for_id' => 'user_id']],
            [['username'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['username' => 'username']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'user_equip_id' => 'User Equip ID',
            'phone_model' => 'Phone Model',
            'phone_series' => 'Phone Series',
            'phone_date_acq' => 'Phone Date Acq',
            'nb_sg_model' => 'Nb Sg Model',
            'nb_sg_series' => 'Nb Sg Series',
            'nb_sg_date_acq' => 'Nb Sg Date Acq',
            'display_model' => 'Display Model',
            'display_series' => 'Display Series',
            'display_date_acq' => 'Display Date Acq',
            'user_for_id' => 'User For ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[UserFor]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUserFor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_for_id']);
    }
    
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['username' => 'username']);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return EquipmentQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new EquipmentQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\EquipmentSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Equipments';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="equipment-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Equipment', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'username',
            #'user_equip_id',
            'phone_model',
            'phone_series',
            'phone_date_acq',
            'nb_sg_model',
            'nb_sg_series',
            'nb_sg_date_acq',
            'display_model',
            'display_series',
            'display_date_acq',
            //'user_for_id',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getUsername()` method implicates that there is foreign key `username` in the `equipment` and `user` table which is not true.

To get `username` of the user use the relation method you already set like:

```
$equipment->userFor->username;
```

`userFor` calls `getUserFor()` and returns the relation model from which you can get `username`.

In the GridView you can use `userFor.username` to get this value on the grid.

I can see you have set the `username` in the equipment's rules which implicates you want to pass it to the model when creating or updating it - since this is not an equipment's field it will not make equipment and user connected without extra code you need to prepare first.